# How to negate a program's error code for an if statement in fish shell?

Tags: shell, fish

I wanted to do something like either of these statements, that is probably like bash, but received errors:

```
if ! prog ...
  ....
```

**Error:** `fish: Unknown command '! prog ...'`

```
if test ! prog ...
  ....
```

**Error:** `test: Expected a combining operator like '-a' at index 2`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for the `not` keyword:

```
if not false
   echo Foo
end
```

Comment: I just ran into this again tonight, and didn't realize this replaced the `test` command at first..  Not exactly what I would want, but just noting this here.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up just using `$status`.

```
if test "$status" != "0"
  ...
```

I don't like to separate the statement from where I check its error code in case of future accidental code maintenance inserts other statements in between, even as nearly harmless as `echo`, but I could not find another way to use a program call on the test line to get the negated condition I wanted.

I guess I could wrap some of that 'status' and negating logic into a function, but that just seems like more work, and I'm hoping I'm missing a more succinct syntax as a conditional statement.